# jQuery tag cloud plugin help

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, tag-cloud

If you look at the following Jquery plugin. Under the power heading, Im wondering if it would be possible to have the same smaller to larger effect, but in a particular direction, say north west for example

http://www.pritaeas.net/public/jquery/jquery.tagcloud.0.5.0/index.html

further to this, would the jquery ui position plugin work well with is so elements do not over lap

Thanks all

Comment: There are serveral discussions on stackOverflow regarding creating such a cloud yourself.
You might want to check out "wordle" and similar projects and the realted discussions here.
You might be able to either rewrite the jquery plugin or even go so far as to build your own version.
To answer your question: Yes! It is possible!

Answer (score 0):

Head Tags Add

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.pritaeas.net/public/jquery/jquery.tagcloud.0.5.0/scripts/jquery-1.2.6.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.pritaeas.net/public/jquery/jquery.tagcloud.0.5.0/scripts/jquery.tagcloud.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.pritaeas.net/public/jquery/jquery.tagcloud.0.5.0/scripts/jquery.tinysort.min.js"></script>
```

Body Tags Add

```
<?php echo "<ul>";for($x=0;$x<100;$x++){
            echo '<li value="'.floor(100-$x).'"><a href="#'.$x.'" >d'.$x.'n</a></li>';
} echo "</ul>";?>
```

Footer Add

```
<script>$("ul").tagcloud();</script>
```